# Java Convert double to int

Tags: java

I have this code, and the input in the textfield is 50, so its output should be 25,
but there is a error, because no output

```
button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    String tfg = textField.getText().toString();
    String tfc = textField.getText();

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(textField.getText().toString().equals("0") || 
            textField.getText().toString().equals("") || 
            textField.getText().toString().equals(" ") || 
            textField.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Cow.this,
                            "Tree Amount Should Be 1 or More",
                            "Invalid Tree Amount",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        if(!tfg.equals("0")) {
            try {
                int tfgg = Integer.parseInt(tfc);
                int trcs = tfgg * 1;
                double trcp = 1 / 2;
                int trcc = (int) trcp * trcs;
                System.out.println(new Integer(trcc).toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException se) {

            }
        }
    }
});
```

I try to convert from my php to that code, here is my php code :

```
$doorSeed = $mount * 1;
$doorPrice = 1 / 2;
$doorConvert = $doorPrice * $doorSeed;
echo "Treasure Chest Seed = ".$doorSeed." Price : ".$doorConvert." World Lock <br>";
```

Comment: you don´t need to do `new Integer`for an int, aswell as `toString()` on a String object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int trcc = (int) trcp * trcs;
```

Try this instead

```
int trcc = (int) (trcp * trcs);
```

You need to cast the `complete expression` [`(trcp * trcs)`] instead of just the first variable `trcp` to `int`. The other variable in the expression `trcs` is of `double` type, so the result of the expression become `double`. That is why you cast the complete expression. So your end result will be `int`

```
     int tfgg = Integer.parseInt(tfc.trim());    // tfc = 4;   tfgg = 4;
     int trcs = tfgg * 1;                 // trcs = 4 * 1 = 5;
     double trcp = 1.0 / 2;               // trcp = 0.5;
     int trcc = (int) (trcp * trcs);      // trcc = (0.5 * 5) = (2.5) = 2;
     System.out.println(trcc);            // 2;

double trcp = 1.0 / 2;
```

Here make at least one value as `double` so the expression will be evaluated as `double` as suggested by @tunaki.

Also you don't need this statement in your code `int trcs = tfgg * 1;`.

**Use like this:**

```
  String tfg ;
  String tfc ;
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    tfg = textField.getText();
    tfc = textField.getText();
    if(textField.getText().equals("0") || textField.getText().equals("") || textField.getText().equals(" ") || textField.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Cow.this,
          "Tree Amount Should Be 1 or More",
          "Invalid Tree Amount",
          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    if(!tfg.equals("0")) {
      try {
        int tfgg = Integer.parseInt(tfc.trim());    // tfc = 4;
        int trcs = tfgg;                 // trcs = 4 * 1 = 5
        double trcp = 1.0 / 2;                 // trcp = 0.5
        int trcc = (int) (trcp * trcs);      // trcc = (0.5 * 5) = (2.5) = 2
        System.out.println("HI: "+trcc);
      } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
      }
```

Comment: @DariusEllertKlaus it should be a mix of @YoungHobbit´s answer and @Tunak´s answer

Comment: int tfgg = Integer.parseInt(tfc);
int trcs = tfgg * 1;
double trcp = 1.0 / 2;
int trcc = (int) (trcp * trcs);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(trcc));

Comment: @DariusEllertKlaus I have taken a sample value an put the calculation step by step.

Comment: Im problem at try and catch,
i try to edit to System.out.println("Hay"); and no output, but when i remove the try and catch, i have output Hay, but get error NumberFormattedException

Comment: @DariusEllertKlaus Could you try printing content of `tfc`, it might causing this. Try this `int tfgg = Integer.parseInt(tfc.trim())`.

Comment: Still can't im confused

Comment: @DariusEllertKlaus what should be input and output for this?

Comment: @YoungHobbit What do you mean?

Comment: @DariusEllertKlaus I have got it. check the anwer,

Comment: Awesome Thanks Very VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY MUCH !

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at this line:

```
double trcp = 1 / 2;
```

This does *not* result in `trcp = 0.5` but `trcp = 0.0`, because you are dividing integer values (and so are using integer division).

You should use the following code:

```
double trcp = 1.0 / 2;
```

to force division using doubles.

Other comments:

- `new Integer(trcc).toString()` should be replaced with `String.valueOf(trcc)`.
- Avoid using empty catch statements: at minimum, log the exception
- What's the point of this line: `int trcs = tfgg * 1;`?

Comment: you could also add `textField.getText().toString();` and the usage of `!textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()` instead of `textField.getText().toString().equals("")` and `textField.getText().toString().equals(" ")` to the comment list :).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have this `(int)0.5 = 0`.
In your case, `trcp = 0.5` and is double, so when it's cast to integer the result is 0.

And when you do `(int)a + b`, the true operation with parenthesis for priority here is: `((int)a)+(b)`, so what you have to is the following:

```
int trcc = (int) (trcp * trcs);
```

instead of the following:

```
int trcc = (int) trcp * trcs;
```